# Индексация файлов в проекте Xcode

Tags: xcode

С некоторых пор (возможно с установки Xcode 4.5 но не уверен) каждый раз при открытии проекта в Xcode происходит индексация файлов проекта, что отображается в меню сверху посередине. Это никак особо не напрягает, но занимает обычно несколько секунд. Интересно, за это может отвечать какая-то настройка и у всех ли так или это что-то я ненароком изменил?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После обновления до 4.6 вопрос плавно исчез, видимо ровно стали пакеты при обновлении